# How to retrieve a password from Keychain command-line?

Tags: command-line, keychain

According to many pages, it should be easy to retrieve command line a password using `security`.

I tried several options without success:

[image]

```
$sudo security list-keychains  
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
$sudo security find-generic-password -s "proxy_test"
    The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
$sudo security find-generic-password -s "proxy_test" -a "collector" -g
    The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
$sudo security find-generic-password -s "socks://proxy_test"
    The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
$sudo security find-key -s "proxy_test"
    The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
$sudo security unlock "login"
...
$sudo security find-key -s "proxy_test"
    The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
...
long etc. with sudo/without sudo.
```

Comment: sudo security find-internet-password -gs proxy_test - Try this ?

Answer (score 6):

Seems proxy as part of internet, require another command:

```
security find-internet-password -s "proxy_test" -g
```

Comment: See the "Kind" column :-)

Comment: I was writing in the comment box, but you figure out your answer quickly :)

Comment: You can still publish your answer an I would accept it. I know it's not a big reward anyway. Thank you

Comment: @AdrianMaire: It's fine as people will see your answer as a solution which should be enough for this community.